# What kind of window do I have?

Tags: hvac

The window in my apartment is making installing a window AC very difficult and it doesn’t help that I don’t know the type and Google is not helping me.

For context, the bedroom window in question is horizontal, and slides to the left and right. From where I stand in my bedroom, the window opens from the left and from the right side all the way. There is a space, which is wood, then there are 2 more glass panels of window attached to the exterior of the building, and only the right side slides open, which is what my window screen is behind.

Whichever fashion all sliding panes are in, there is still a ~3 inch gap of wood between them. 4 panes of glass in total, 3 of them slide, and one is not operational, and there is no screen behind the window pane that doesn’t move.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sliding windows can be hard to fit ACs to. Check what your neighbors have done; presumably they faced the same problem when installing their own AC.

Answer (score 3):

That window's a common sliding window, and there's airconditioner designs that work well with them

While I've not seen them in a while - but you're looking for a 'casement' style airconditioning unit *or* at a pinch, a portable unit, which'll dump the hot exhaust air out a tube, and there's a panel to block out the window opening. They are *generally* not as good as a 'real' window unit - but the former is *designed* to fit into that style of window, with a frame, and bellows style bit to block the top part of it.

Random googled image for reference

[image]

Portable units generally come with a air blocking plate to dump  hot air out which'll also fit into a sliding window, which'll work here too.

Comment: Great answer! I'll note that simply turning a "standard" window AC unit on its side to fit in like this probably is _not_ a good idea. Nothing in the unit is designed to work 90° off its design axis. Find a unit designed to be installed vertically even if it costs a few more `<units of currency>`.

Comment: Yup, these are a *specific* type - meant for this. They've gotten less common here since most apartments have 'dedicated' window AC slots, or gone for multi split units - but they're still a thing as far as I know